# how to add validator in network using subxt

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node, validator

I am using `subxt` library . I have downloaded metadata from chain using this url **wss://rpc.polkadot.io:443 ** . I want to know how can i add validator to the chain using subxt
library .

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do using Subxt here? I'd encourage you to look at the docs on setting up a new validator here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot. There are some transactions you can submit as part of the process to get a new validator going, and if you wanted to use Subxt for those then have a look at https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/book/usage/transactions/index.html (and related docs) to learn about how to submit transactions via Subxt :)